# Is there a "standard" way to construct an HTTP GET request for an API?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, https, http-headers

I'm trying to work with a new API provided by a messaging service.

Their documentation says their API can be queried with a "standard" HTTPS "GET" request.

Now to me, GET request URLS look like this:

https://api.domain.com/path/subpath/?params&otherparams

I should be able to construct the above using their "documentation", which is an example given in node.js:

```
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "api-cpaas.dotdigital.com",
  "auth": "apiuser:password",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/messages/{Message Id}",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

Example message ID: 6df8b42b-7165-4099-bd9b-356b2f41f1a9

Published here:
https://developer-cpaas.dotdigital.com/reference/getting-message-statuses

But no matter what I try I always get a "404" error.

I don't know node.js so I can't interpret their example, and they don't offer any other examples. What should the actual GET request for this service should look like?

Comment: Why are you setting `null` for the port? Https port is 443.

Comment: I am assuming your 404 is coming from `/messages/{Message Id}`, as that path will not exist on the server.